# _wfopen won't compile with wchar.h

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors

I am trying to use `_wfopen` in my C code. 
I compile using `gcc filename.c -o filename` from the commandline in Cygwin.

`_wfopen` is ideally supposed to be defined in the header file `wchar.h`
When I grep for wfopen in `/usr/inculde` , I see the following line in `tchar.h`.
`#define _tfopen _wfopen`
I do not see the definition of the function anywhere. I have included both `tchar.h` and `wchar.h` header files. But my code won't compile.

Error seen:

```
myloadfile.c:68:18: warning: implicit declaration of function _wfopen
Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     filehandle = _wfopen(lpwConfigFile,L"r");
                  ^~~~~~~
myloadfile.c:68:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without >a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     filehandle = _wfopen(lpwConfigFile,L"r");
                ^
/tmp/ccQBkrlQ.o:myloadDLL.c:(.text+0x189): undefined reference to`_wfopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: do you have `_UNICODE` defined anywhere in your code?

Comment: *Cygwin* tries to offer *Ux* like interface for *Win*, while *wchar.h* (*tchar.h*) is a *Win* implementation for *UNICODE*s. Why are you trying to mix the 2? There's no logical reason to do so. BTW, the func is defined in *VStudio Runtime Library*: (*msvcrt\*.dll* or one of *vcruntime\*.dll*'s clients (typically *ucrtbase.dll*)).